# Why doesn't my catch-all Route work in my Switch?

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I have an existing application that I'm trying to upgrade from react-route v2 to react-router v4. How can I render a catch-all route if nothing else matches? Here's what I have so far:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <About />
  <Route component={Splat} />
</Switch>
```

The `<About />` component contains its own routes:

```
<div>
  <Route path="/foo/one" component={One} />
  <Route path="/bar/two" component={Two} />
</div>
```

With this setup, I'm never able to render the `Splat` route since it thinks `About` is a match.

This Codepen should illustrate my issue -
 https://codepen.io/justinpincar/pen/xrqQEZ

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're rendering `About` inside the `Switch`. It's not that it thinks `About` is a match, it's that `About` has no match criteria that it renders all the time. The `About` component contains static JSX that will appear on all routes *except `/` because it is the first route*. When you substitute the JSX from `About` in, you get:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>This is about</p>
    <Route path="/foo/one" component={One} />
    <Route path="/bar/two" component={Two} />
  </div>      
  <Route component={Splat} />
</Switch>
```

Here, the `div` is inside the `Switch`. When you have children, such as the `div` and routes here, in a `Switch`, **only one child is rendered at a time** -- like a switch.

Thus, when you navigate to *any other route aside from `/`*, the first route, `/` doesn't match, it goes to the next child. The next child is the `div` which *is not a route itself so there are no criteria for where it is rendered*. Thus, it is rendered on *every single route*. The last route is never reached in the `Switch` because the `div` has no path, so it is statically rendered and thus shows up everywhere except `/`.

Instead, set up a route for your `About` component so it has a path criteria for where to render:

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

Then, because your `One` and `Two` routes shouldn't be nested (as they don't share the common path `/about`), give them their own routes by moving them out of `About`. Then in the `One` and `Two` components, render `About`. [Here's an updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRvQGm).

Comment: This is mostly correct, but the reason that the `<About>` (or `<div>`) always renders is that is it treated as a pathless `<Route>` and pathless `<Route>`s always match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In the actual project, the <About> component has a whole bunch of common logic that both <One> and <Two> use heavily - so it's important for me to keep that container. I understand your point on having a common parent path of `/about`... but it seems silly to change all the routes just to use the latest version of this library. Telling my client I have to completely refactor their codebase to make the catchall page work isn't going to go over well :-) Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Justin Could you explain, as in give an example of the common logic? You may need to refactor some components.

Comment: Sure, e.g. wrapper components of <SignedIn> and <SignedOut> enclose a whole bunch of the routes, doing things like rendering different layouts and setting up different event listeners. I could prefix everything so each group shares a common path (/signed-in/, /signed-out/), but that really isn't ideal.

Comment: @Justin If they don't share a common path then they shouldn't be routes nested in routes. I'm really not sure I can really help without more code, and that would be out of the scope of this question. Asking another question with actual code would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5261

Per their recommendation, either:

```
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const One = (props) => (
  <About>
    <div>Page One</div>
  </About>
)

const Two = (props) => (
  <About>
    <div>Page Two</div>
  </About>
)

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/foo/one' component={One} />
    <Route exact path='/bar/two' component={Two} />
    <Route component={Splat} />
  </Switch>
)
```

Or:

```
// you have to use component, not render or children
const AboutRoute = ({ component:Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    <About>
      <Component {...props} />
    </About>
  )} />
)

const One = (props) => (
  <div>Page One</div>
);

const Two = (props) => (
  <div>Page Two</div>
);


const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <AboutRoute exact path='/foo/one' component={One} />
    <AboutRoute exact path='/bar/two' component={Two} />
    <Route component={Splat} />
  </Switch>
)
```

Thanks for the prompt answers, super helpful!